# Use java library in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a project in Java. This project has a class *com.xyz.api.base.models.mongo.Member*.

I want to import this Java project to a Scala project to use Member class.

However, I got this error (the library is already downloaded to Scala dependencies):

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.mongo.Member`

The strange thing is that there is not compilation error. The error above only happens at runtime. Furthermore, the error message does not mention *com.xyz.api.base* as the base package of *models.mongo.Member*.

My code:

```
import com.redmart.api.base.models.mongo.Member
import com.redmart.api.base.utils.RedisCacheImpl
import redis.RedisClient

object Redis extends App {
  implicit val akkaSystem = akka.actor.ActorSystem()
  val host: String = "127.0.0.1"
  val port: Int = 6379
  val db: Int = 0
  val timeout: Long = 10000L

  val key = "a2IxSE5kdW9HRHZUe"
  var redisCacheImpl: RedisCacheImpl = _
  try {
    RedisCacheImpl.configRedis(host, port, db, timeout)
    redisCacheImpl = RedisCacheImpl.getInstance()
    val obj = redisCacheImpl.get(key)
    val member = obj.asInstanceOf[Member]
    println(s"member id ${member.getMemberId}")
  }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please show some code, most importantly your imports.
Also, are you sure you included your java files in your classpath?

Comment: I added the code. Please take a look.

Answer (score -1):

In this case spring-boot's version 1.2.3.RELEASE use `mongo-java-driver 2.12.5`. for more details go through this documentation :[Link](https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/com/mongodb/MongoException.DuplicateKey.html)